# How to translate using I18n options for select [Rails 3]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**How to translate using I18n options for select**

**Colleagues, tell me please, how can I do**

```
<%= date_select :user, :birthday,
  {:start_year => Time.now.year,
  :end_year => 1900,
  :use_short_month => false,
  :order => [:day, :month, :year],
  :prompt => {:month => 'Month', :day => 'Day', :year => 'Year'}},
  {:class => 'userBirthday',
  :id => 'userBirthday'}
%>

<%= select :user, :gender, ([["Male", "male"], ["Female", "female"]]), :class => 'bigselect' %>
```

Comment: `t("Male")` does not work?

Answer (score 0):

**I forgot to add  in locale files this:**

```
es:
  date:
    abbr_day_names:
    - dom
    - lun
    - mar
    - mié
    - jue
    - vie
    - sáb
    abbr_month_names:
    - 
    - ene
    - feb
    - mar
    - abr
    - may
    - jun
    - jul
    - ago
    - sep
    - oct
    - nov
    - dic
    day_names:
    - domingo
    - lunes
    - martes
    - miércoles
    - jueves
    - viernes
    - sábado
    formats:
      default: ! '%d/%m/%Y'
      long: ! '%d de %B de %Y'
      short: ! '%d de %b'
    month_names:
    - 
    - enero
    - febrero
    - marzo
    - abril
    - mayo
    - junio
    - julio
    - agosto
    - septiembre
    - octubre
    - noviembre
    - diciembre
    order:
    - :day
    - :month
    - :year
.......
...
..
```

all in this link: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/es.yml

and for option for select correctly is: <%= select :user, :gender, ([[t("Male"), "male"], [t("Female"), "female"]]), :class => 'bigselect' %> thanks for reminding me @Kaeros